# Display user input for form

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, innerhtml, getelementbyid

So I made a form with multiple inputs. I want to display the user's inputs on the same page after they click submit. However, my code only displays the first input. For some reason it does not catch the others. Also, required fields are being overridden by the java i coded. Here is my html:

```
<body>
  <div class = "content">
        <h2>Provide Your Contact Information</h2>
        <form id="theForm" method="get" action="submitData">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size = "25" id="user_input" name="name" placeholder="Type your first name" /></td>
            <tr>
                    <td>Middle name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size = "25" id="user_input" name="mname" placeholder="Type your middle name" /></td>
            <tr>
                    <td>Last name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" size = "25" id="user_input" name="lname" placeholder="Type your last name" required/></td>

  </table>
        <table>
            <h3>Provide your login access information</h3>
            <tr>
                <td>Login ID:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="user_input" name="login" placeholder="Type a login id" required/></td>
        </table>

    </form>
    </div>
        <div class = "contentright">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" onclick="showInput();" ></td>
                <td><label>Your input: </label><br /></td>
                <td><p><span id='display'></span> </p></td>
        </div>
```

My java code:

```
 function showInput() 
{
        var message_entered =  document.getElementById("user_input").value;

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;
}
```

Thanks

UPDATE****

```
 function validateForm() {
    return (isNotEmpty("name", "Please enter your name!")
    && isNotEmpty("lname", "Please enter your last name!")
    && isSelected("city", "Please make a selection!")
    && isSelected("state", "Please make a selection!")
    && isNumeric("zipcode", "Please enter a 5-digit zip code!")
    && isLengthMinMax("zipcode", "Please enter a 5-digit zip code!", 5, 5)
    && isNumeric("phone", "Please enter a valid phone number!")
    && isValidEmail("email", "Enter a valid email!")
    && isLengthMinMax("login", "Enter a valid login id!", 10, 25)
    && isLengthMinMax("password", "Enter a valid password!", 6, 8));
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is for example for zip code I only want the user to be able to enter 5 digits. I also want to validate the things like the email or password.

Comment: You should use different id attributes for different html controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just catching 1 input. The right way to do that is by catching all the inputs and iterate trough them in a loop.

```
 function showInput() 
{   
    var form = document.forms[0].elements;
    var message_entered = "";

    for(var i = 0, j = form.length;i < j;i++) 
    {

        if(form[i].type == "text") {message_entered += (form[i].value + " - ");}

    }

    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message_entered;

}
```

You also might want to give different id's to your inputs.

Check here the example working: http://jsfiddle.net/vjk3zngh/

Comment: thank you! Now my problem is with the required inputs. Pop ups should show when the user does not answer the required fields.

Comment: The code I put is an example of what I tried I open to different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're giving the same ID to all the inputs. They will overlap and you'll end up only having the last result. Try switching to different ID's or instead use a class.